# Link tag to include html templates

Tags: html

index.html has,

```
<html>
  <body>
    Main layout
    <link rel="import" href="a.html" />
  </body>
</html>
```

a.html has,

```
inner content!!!
```

When i open these pages using `node-static`, i see output as,

```
Main Layout
```

But i like to have,

```
Main Layout
inner content!!!
```

In summary, how to break my html file into seperate blocks & add/remove them on the fly??

Comment: Could be duplicate of this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: what does the tag 'hyperlink' have to do with this question? a hyperlink is the `<a>` anchor tag, not a `<link>` tag. or is there something i'm completely getting wrong about your question?